# Unable to find folders in the directory tree in Android (Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin, storage-access-framework, saf

I'm encountering difficulties in my Android application while attempting to access and process folders within a directory tree. The provided code snippet aims to traverse a directory tree and identify folders for further processing. However, despite the presence of folders in the specified directory, the code doesn't seem to recognize or retrieve these folders using listFiles(). This behavior persists despite correct directory URIs being passed.

```
private fun processDirectoryPath(directoryUri: Uri) {
    val childrenUri = DocumentsContract.buildChildDocumentsUriUsingTree(
        directoryUri,
        DocumentsContract.getTreeDocumentId(directoryUri)
    )
    Log.d("Folder Manager", "DEBUG?$directoryUri")
    val docTree = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(this, childrenUri)
    val images = ArrayList<Pair<String, Bitmap>>()
    var errorFound = false
    if (docTree!!.listFiles().isNotEmpty()) {
        for (doc in docTree.listFiles()) {
            if (doc.isDirectory && !errorFound) {

                // ...
            }
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

I've implemented the code to traverse the directory tree using DocumentsContract.buildChildDocumentsUriUsingTree and DocumentFile.fromTreeUri. I expected the listFiles() method to return the list of folders within the specified directory tree. However, it appears that the listFiles() call doesn't recognize the folders, resulting in an empty list or no traversal into the directories.

Comment: `folders within a directory tree. ` Please start your post with telling how you obtained that tree.

Comment: The directory tree was acquired from another function when some images were saved to a specific location.

Comment: Can be. But that does not tell us anything yet about how the tree was obtained.

Comment: Is there a reason why you are using `DocumentsContract`, rather than just consistently using `DocumentFile`? For example, if `directoryUri` represents a document tree that you obtained previously, have you tried using it directly with `DocumentFile.fromTreeUri()`?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! Initially, I chose DocumentsContract for managing document access because it offered a method (buildChildDocumentsUriUsingTree) that facilitated building child document URIs. Being relatively new to Kotlin, I relied on this solution found online. I tried also to use directly DocumentFile.fromTreeUri() but it was the same. However, considering the document tree created by my app from another function, I attempted using File.listFiles() as an alternative to address the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering the document tree created by my app from another function, I attempted using File.listFiles() as an alternative to address the issue.

```
    private fun processDirectoryPath(directoryPath: String) {
    val files = File(directoryPath).listFiles()
    val images = ArrayList<Pair<String, Bitmap>>()
    var errorFound = false

    if (files != null) {
        for (file in files) {
            if (file.isDirectory) {
                // ....
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question or are you still evaluating?